# How optimized are Java 8 stream filters over collection methods?

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8

For example I have a comma separated string:

```
String multiWordString= "... , ... , ... ";
```

And I want to check whether another string str is present in the csv string.
Then I can do following 2 things:

1.

```
boolean contains = Arrays.asList(multiWordString.split(",")).contains(str);
```

2.

```
boolean contains = Arrays.asList(multiWordString.split(",")).stream().filter(e -> e.equals(str)).findFirst();
```

**EDIT:** The sample string happens to use comma as a delimiter. I should have used the better name for sample string to avoid confusion. 
I updated the name. In this question I am trying to find the performance difference between using Java 8  streams and loops/collection methods.

Comment: Take a look at this useful [link](http://java.amitph.com/2014/01/java-8-streams-api-laziness.html)

Comment: Can't a good regex be used in here?

Comment: Obi wan: depends on the csv content. But yes regexes would work, as I answered hours ago :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without tests it's impossible to tell, details internally can change of how one solutions of another acts, so the best way is to measure. It is know though that streams are a bit slower - they do have an infrastructure behind them...

Here is a naive simple test (**with little data**):

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class CSVParsing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder().include(CSVParsing.class.getSimpleName())
                .jvmArgs("-ea")
                .shouldFailOnError(true)
                .build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    @Param(value = { "a,e, b,c,d",
            "a,b,c,d, a,b,c,da,b,c,da,b,c,da,b,c,da,b,c,da,b,c,da,b,c,da,b,c,d, e",
            "r, m, n, t,r, m, n, tr, m, n, tr, m, n, tr, m, n, tr, m, n, tr, m, n, tr, m, n, t, e" })
    String csv;

    @Fork(1)
    @Benchmark
    public boolean containsSimple() {
        return Arrays.asList(csv.split(",")).contains("e");
    }

    @Fork(1)
    @Benchmark
    public boolean containsStream() {
        return Arrays.asList(csv.split(",")).stream().filter(e -> e.equals("e")).findFirst().isPresent();
    }

    @Fork(1)
    @Benchmark
    public boolean containsStreamParallel() {
        return Arrays.asList(csv.split(",")).stream().filter(e -> e.equals("e")).findFirst().isPresent();
    }
}
```

Even if you don't understand the code the results are simple numbers that you can compare:

```
 CSVParsing.containsSimple   (first Parameter)    181.201 ±   5.390
 CSVParsing.containsStream                        255.851 ±   5.598
 CSVParsing.containsStreamParallel                295.296 ±  57.800
```

I am not going to show the rest of the results (for other parameters) since they are in the same range.

Bottom line is they do differ, by **up to 100 ns**; let me re-iterate that: **nano-seconds**.

There is a difference indeed; but if *you really honestly care* about this diff, then csv parsing is probably the wrong choice in the first place.

Comment: Note that each of your tests contains the base costs of `Arrays.asList(csv.split(","))` which are not related to the stream vs. collection operation. Unless you add another test, `Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(csv)`, showing a genuine stream operation without an intermediate array/collection…

Comment: @Holger well yes, but they *all* have this cost. That cost is included in each test, skewing all them equally because of that. I thought of providing just the `array of Strings` to each benchmark method, but that would make the code more complicated.

Comment: Of course, these costs are included in all of them. But as long as you don’t know the ratio between these base costs and the costs you are comparing, the result is meaningless. It might be that the ratio between `containsSimple` and `containsStream` is indeed roughly `181:255`, but it’s also possible that the base costs are `180`, and the ratio between `containsSimple` and `containsStream` is `1:75`. Who knows?

Comment: On the other hand, if you say you *want* to compare the split+search operation as a whole, it’s unfair to let the stream variant create that collection too, when the Stream API actually allows to process the data without, as you are dropping a major benefit of the Stream API, the possibility to do the split lazily too.

Comment: @Holger indeed! but I did not think about this at all, only tested the code that OP provided. A bit un-clear though. You do mean that there should be another test `Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(csv)`. This one would not create the array, but it would introduce the Pattern matching cost then.

Comment: The preparation would introduce a different kind of base cost, on the other hand, it does not only skip the array creation, it will only match as many `,` as required to find the matching string in the chained `filter` operation when using `findFirst`. This can pay off greatly for large strings containing a match. Since the total outcome depends on the input, adding another separate test would be useful.

Comment: @Eugene I had framed the question wrong way. I was not interested in csv files. I was interested in figuring out the performance of streams vs collection methods.I just took a comma separated string as an example but made the overall question confusing. But your answer has helped anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The "amount" of work is the same in both versions: a list needs to be created and all elements need to be compared.

Option 2 adds the overhead of setting up a lot of things behind the covers. Thus option 2 draws significantly more CPU cycles compared to option 1. Streams do not come for free!

Efficiency has different aspects here. When your csv input is relatively simple, a regular expression might do fine (to check if some pattern could be found in the csv string. And when you have to deal with arbitrary csv input (for example with values that contain quoted commas) then that simple split by comma will lead to incorrect results anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Watch out, CSVs are generally more complex then just comma's seperating strings, theres escaping comma's to worry about as well. I hope this is either an example or not a CSV format being imported.

You shouldn't convert from an array to a list first, go straight from the array to the stream using Arrays.stream or Stream.of()

But the streams are lazy, and they only do as much work as they need to do.

.contains(str) will abort as soon as it finds a match.

It's hard to tell performance without measuring it, so for now make the program correct and easy to maintain.

If performance is a concern, after you have some amount done, profile and see what bits could be better, try alternatives, then pick the winner.